# Where is the PS1 prompt variable set in ash shell?

Tags: prompt, busybox, ash

I have a NAS drive from Western Digital. I can ssh into it, and when I log in, the first line that appears is:

`BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-10-30 15:28:59 CST) built-in shell (ash)`

I don't like the default prompt that I get (`echo $PS1` gives `\u@\h \W \$`). However, I can't find where this PS1 variable is set. My user is `root` and the only file in `/home/root/` is `.ash_history`, and if I do a grep within the `/etc/` directory, I get no results for `PS1`.

How can I find where the PS1 variable is set?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191917/1721265 the `busybox` `ash` is essentially `dash` - see http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash for documentation.

Comment: What makes you think that the PS1 setting you don't like is set somewhere, rather than being the default?

Comment: Some systems drop root user directly to /. Check if you have `/.profile` for example. FHS says that root could have home in /root so also check `/root/.profile` - it would work if `login` applet was used. It doesn't look like a default bbox ash prompt, default prompt is `\w \$` but it's possible that WD has modified bbox source code.

Answer (score 3):

Ed Grimm's comment got me thinking of an obvious workaround – I didn't know there was such a thing as a "default". If there's just a default prompt, and no `PS1` variable set anywhere, well no wonder I can't find the file where `PS1` is set – it doesn't exist (yet).

So, I just created a `.profile` file within `/home/root` and set the `PS1` variable to the format I desire. Now, when I log in to the NAS, this `.profile` file is automatically read and the prompt displays just how I want.

Comment: This is definitely an answer!

Comment: My `.profile` file was working just fine for me, until I ssh'd into my NAS today - the file had disappeared. I can only assume that a recent firmware update (which the NAS does automatically) deleted the file. Just something to keep in my mind in case anyone else encounters a similar situation to mine.

Comment: My /root/.profile is not executed when I start 'ash'. Any hints anyone?